# Angular: фильтры по содержанию

Tags: filter, angularjs, javascript

Есть "сложная" структура данных, которые вписываются в DOM посредством ngRepeat. Как полагается философией AngularJS, я фильтрую данные по точка фильтрации настраиваемые из соседнего блока "фильтры". Но беда заключается в том, что есть фильтры касаются внутреннего состояния выводимых данных. Т.е. фильтровать нужно по совпадению внутреннего представления данных с фильтром.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVfX9/)

Для наглядности я откинул саму настройку фильтра и реальную сложности данных, оставив только актуальную задачу. Комментарий в коде должен помочь понять суть вопроса лучше.

Comment: @Алексей Данчин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что вам мешает создать свой фильтр? http://jsfiddle.net/LVfX9/1/